# What's the difference between function that returns float and float&?

Tags: c++, reference, return, return-value, return-type

What's the difference in usage of function get1() and get2()?

```
struct x
{
    float get1() const
    {
        float fx = 4;
        fx += 1.5f;
        return fx;
    }

    float& get2() const
    {
        float fx = 4;
        fx += 1.5f;
        return fx;
    }
};

int main()
{
    x t;
    float x1 = t.get1();
    float/*&*/ x2 = t.get2();
    cout << x1 << endl;
    cout << x2 << endl;
    cin.get();
}
```

As i understand, get2() can only be const class member..
It's not clear for me completely. If someone can point me to a reference or just a short but complete solution, would be nice.

Comment: If you return a reference, the referenced object **must live long enough**! Yours has lifetime restricted by the function invocation... [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6441218)

Comment: Both methods can be const *or* non-const, because they don't rely on `this` being a pointer-to-non-const-`x`.

Comment: Yep, my mistake with const.

Comment: You return by non-const reference when you want the caller to be able to modify the object to which the reference refers. In this example however, you're returning a reference to a local variable, which has Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. The last question: will value be copied if function returns float&, but i store it in float variable, not float& ?

Comment: @DmitrijA Yes, it will be copied.

Comment: Please don't change the code after people answered your question. It invalidates existing answers creating confusion for everybody, including those that will view you question in some months.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case, `get2()` invokes undefined behavior because you return a reference to a method-local that goes out of scope.

The difference is that returning `float` returns a `float` value, while `float &` returns a reference to a `float`.  The reference can be used to alter the data of the referent; when returning by value you just get a copy.

It sounds like you are just confused about what references do, so here is the colloquial definition: a reference is another name for an object.  That means that a reference *requires* the existence of its target to exist elsewhere, very similar to a (non-null) pointer.

Let me write a better example to illustrate the difference:

```
struct x
{
    x() : data(0) { }

    float get1() const
    {
        return data;
    }

    // Cannot be const now, because we can't return a non-const reference to what
    // would be a const data member. (If this method were const then data would be a
    // const float, and that cannot bind to float &.)
    float & get2()
    {
        return data;
    }

private:
    float data;
};
```

Now we have two methods, one that returns `data` and one that returns a reference to it.  The difference here is that with `get2()` you can actually change the value of `x::data`:

```
x an_x;

float a = an_x.get1(); // a is 0
a = 5;                 // a is 5, an_x.data is still 0
a = x.get1();          // a is 0 again, because an_x.data did not change

float & b = an_x.get2(); // b is 0
b = 5;                   // b is 5, and so is an_x.data!
a = x.get1();            // a is now 5, because an_x.data is 5
```

Notably, returning a reference makes the result of the expression an lvalue:

```
an_x.get1() = 5; // Compile-time error, because a float is not an lvalue.
an_x.get2() = 5; // Compiles, and sets an_x.data to 5.
```

This is a technique used by the standard library containers; `vector<int>` for example returns `int &` from its non-const `operator[]` overload, which is why `some_vector[0] = 5;` compiles and works as you would expect.

Answer (score 1):

`float fx = 4;`

In your case `fx` is local variable. It will die once you come out of function. If you are returning `float` then you are making copy of value, so even `fx` die, no problem. But if you are returning `float&`, you are returning reference to died variable. Which is undefined behaviour.

Copying is costly operation. When you return reference, you are not making actual copy, but you are returning address of varaiable. You should return reference if your variable will alive after returning from function. But in your case, `fx` will die once you come out of function.

Comment: what is type of t.get2()? Can you please update it in your question.

Comment: fixed now. But still a bit unclear what's the purpose of usage float& variables, while i can use normal float. Is reference behaves like a pointer in that case?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Sure. Updating it.

Comment: Are you referring to `fx` or `x` in the first paragraph? It doesn't make much sense if you're talking about `fx` since it isn't being returned from anywhere.

Comment: I am referring to `fx`. In question op returned `fx` (return fx;). I am getting something wrong?

Comment: @0x499602D2 OK. no problem.

Answer (score 1):

I simulated your case in below blocks of code, you can compare the output of two case for making clearly. Hope it help.

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
    public:
    A()
    {
        std::cout << this << ": A()\n";
    }

    A(const A&)
    {
        std::cout << this << ": Copy constructor\n";
    }

    ~A()
    {
        std::cout << this << ": ~A()\n";
    }
};

struct x
{
    A get1() const
    {
        A a;
        return a;
    }

    A &get2() const
    {
        A a;
        return a;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    x t;

    /*{
        t.get1();
    }*/

    {
        t.get2();
    }

    std::cin.get();
}
```